# How to display results from a search

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search page on my Angular application. It search for properties (house, apartments ect). The user selects their criteria through a form, this form triggers a function in my component, which hits an endpoint from my API via a service.

The data is saved in my component, and currently I'm logging it to the console.

What would be the best way to display the results on the page.

This is the search page html.

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
      <div class="card-header">Search for a Property</div>
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- County and Town Label-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label class="ml-1" for="county">County</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="town">Town</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
          <!-- County Column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select class ="form-control" id="county" formControlName="county" >
                <option *ngFor="let county of counties" [value]="county.value">
                  {{county.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="town">
                <option *ngFor="let town of towns" [value]="town.value">
                  {{town.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Bed and Bath Label-->
          <div class="row mt-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label class="ml-1" for="min-bedrooms">Min Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="max-bedrooms">Max Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label class="ml-1" for="min-bathrooms">Min Bath</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="max-bathrooms">Max Bath</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="min_bedrooms">
                <option *ngFor="let room of rooms" [value]="room.value">
                  {{room.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="max_bedrooms">
                <option *ngFor="let room of rooms" [value]="room.value">
                  {{room.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="min_bathrooms">
                <option *ngFor="let room of rooms" [value]="room.value">
                  {{room.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="min_bathrooms">
                <option *ngFor="let room of rooms" [value]="room.value">
                  {{room.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="row mt-md-4">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="ml-1" for="min-rent">Min Price</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="max-rent">Max Price</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="ml-1" for="type">Selling Type</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label class="ml-1" for="type">Property Type</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="min_price">
                <option *ngFor="let price of prices" [value]="price.value">
                  {{price.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="max_price">
                <option *ngFor="let price of prices" [value]="price.value">
                  {{price.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="selling_type">
                <option *ngFor="let type of sellingTypes" [value]="type.value">
                  {{type.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="property_type">
                <option *ngFor="let type of propertytypes" [value]="type.value">
                  {{type.display}}
                </option>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the component linked to the HTML

```
export class PropertySearchComponent implements OnInit {
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchParams: any = {};
  property: Property;

  constructor(private advertService: AdvertService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createSearchForm();
  }

  createSearchForm() {
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      county: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      town: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_bedrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_bedrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_bathrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_bathrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_price: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_price: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      selling_type: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      property_type: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
    });
  }

  search() {
    this.searchParams.county = (Object.assign({}, this.searchForm.value));
    this.advertService.propertySearch(this.searchParams).subscribe(data => {
      this.property = data;
      console.log(this.property);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

In the search() function above the property search results are saved in this.property.

This is the function in my service that is called from the component.

```
 propertySearch(model: any): Observable<Property> {
    return this.http.post<Property>(environment.apiUrl + 'search', model);
  }
```

How should I go about displaying the results saved in this.property.

Comment: So your question boils down to "how do I display an array of objects?", I guess. Just use another `ngFor` loop, like you already do.

Comment: Can I do it on the same html page as my search form?

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. I kinda feel stupid now. It was so obvious

Comment: Don't feel stupid, everybody has been where you are :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a table with  contain your fields.

And display like this, i assume your property variable has these id, name, email, website.

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20%">
        ID
      </th>
      <th style="width: 50%">
        Name
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10%">
        Email
      </th>
      <th style="width: 20%">
        Website
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of property">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td>{{item.website}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```